# Code First Foreign Key error in Dependent and Principal Roles

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Have been reading other SO posts on this for a while now and there's still something that isn't making sense. Making a MVC application that includes these two classes

```
public class ChecklistFilled
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InternalChecklistFilledID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChecklistFilledDate { get; set; }
    public int PersonnelID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PersonnelID")]
    public virtual Personnel Personnel { get; set; }
    public int EquipmentID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EquipmentID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipment { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemsFilled ItemsFilled { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsFilled
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int InternalItemsFilledID { get; set; }
    public bool? DeviceCondition { get; set; }
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DeviceID")]
    public virtual Device Device { get; set; }
    public int ChecklistFilledID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChecklistFilledID")]
    public virtual ICollection<ChecklistFilled> ChecklistFilled { get; set; }
}
```

And the statement from my DBContext class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ItemsFilled>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.ChecklistFilled)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("ChecklistFilledID"));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

So far I've found a lot of posts that have solutions that are fairly specific to the programmer's problem, and nothing that is straight forward enough for me to apply here as a newer developer. From what I've seen with the DBContext setup, I have it mapping the foreign key as needed from the ChecklistFilled class into the ItemsFilled class, but when I run the enable-migrations command, I get the error

> ItemsFilled_Device_Target_ItemsFilled_Device_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical

Which, taken at face value, is trying to tell me that I must have the same number of properties in each class - and that just sounds absurd to me. So I'm not sure what I need to do to solve this issue and place the ChecklistID into the ItemsFilled table as a FK

Comment: What is relation between ItemsFilled and ChecklistFilled? Do you want to try to implement one-to-many? One ItemsFilled can has many ChecklistFilled?

Comment: A ChecklistFilled can have many ItemsFilled, but a ItemsFilled cannot have many ChecklistFilled.     The ChecklistFilled is the entire checklist, which consists of many Items that need to be 'checked off'

Comment: But what I need is for the ChecklistFilledID to be a foreign key in the ItemsFilled table, to reference which Checklist a group of Items is associated with

Comment: I don't understand that ChecklistFilledID in ItemsFilled table. ItemsFilled table will contains many ChecklistFilled items. It means it will always be associated with many, not with single ChecklistFilledID. Because of that I am thinking that you don't need ChecklistFilledID in ItemsFilled. Anyway I successfully created DB from code first based on your code. I removed Personel and Equipment because I dont have these classes.

Comment: So the thought behind the FK relationship is that the ItemsFilled table will have a long list of items that have been checked off of many different checklists over time. When you want to look and see what checklists were completed with what items, you could query the ItemsFilled table where its ChecklistFilledID matched the ChecklistFilled table's ChecklistFilledID you were interested in

Comment: Joining that with a select on the ChecklistFilled table, you could see who completed a specific checklist, at what time, on what piece of equipment, and what information they marked for each item on the equipment (a device is a single item on an equipment)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, what you want is a relationship where a checklist is related to a list of items, and an item is related to one checklist.

To implement this one-to-many relationship you should redefine the properties in your entities like this:

```
public class ChecklistFilled
{
    ...

    public virtual ICollection<ItemsFilled> ItemsFilled { get; set; }
}

public class ItemsFilled
{
    ...

    public int CheckListFilledId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CheckListFilledId")]
    public virtual ChecklistFilled ChecklistFilled { get; set; }
}
```

With this change you wouldn't even need an explicit mapping in `OnModelInitialize`. In fact, you should remove the mapping.

As a side note, in general it is better if the
`base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);` line is the first one in the method.

The tables generated by the migration look like this (I removed some non-relevant properties for clarity):

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ChecklistFilleds",
            c => new
                {
                    InternalChecklistFilledID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ChecklistFilledDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.InternalChecklistFilledID);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.ItemsFilleds",
            c => new
                {
                    InternalItemsFilledID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    DeviceCondition = c.Boolean(),
                    CheckListFilledId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.InternalItemsFilledID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ChecklistFilleds", t => t.CheckListFilledId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.CheckListFilledId);
```

Perhaps you should consider renaming your entities, the names are a bit confusing, specially when pluralized to compose the tables names. I would suggest `FilledCheckList` and `FilledItem`.

Also, the error you get states that the problematic relationship is `ItemsFilled_Device_Target_ItemsFilled_Device_Source`. It is about `Devices` and `ItemsFilled`. It seems that your code includes some annotation or mapping in the `Device` entity that is causing a problem.